# read (decode) chm file content using java

Tags: java, android, java-native-interface, chm

I want to read & show content's of chm file. What is the encoding of chm file? I don't want to use any library like jchm. I want easiest way to decode chm files & show there contents.

Comment: I'm curious why using a library is not the easiest way to decode it :)

Comment: I am interested in encoding scheme of chm file using library how I can know that?

Comment: Ok. I'm not sure I understood, but you meant "I'm interested in the encoding. If I use a library I coudn't learn it", right?

Comment: yes exactly using library not possible to know chm encoding style

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There's some more documentation on the CHM format here: http://www.russotto.net/chm/chmformat.html which might help you to write your own decoding code if you're not willing to use a library to do it.

Alternatively, there are plenty of freely downloadable decoders that will convert CHM back to HTML - have you considered decoding offline and simply including the decoded files in your application?

Answer (score 3):

According to [Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Microsoft_Compiled_HTML_Help) the file-format has been reverse-engineered and docs are freely available.

http://www.nongnu.org/chmspec/latest/index.html

[http://metacpan.org/pod/Archive::Chm](http://metacpan.org/pod/Archive%3a%3aChm)

I this link -that @Xav provided- is specially concrete on the format:

http://www.russotto.net/chm/chmformat.html